# backdrop-filter and z-index dosen't works together

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
        .container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            padding: 4rem 15rem;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .box1 {
            height: 200px;
            width: 150px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(50, 153, 237, 0.584);
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
            margin: 40px -70px;
            padding: 50px;
            display: flex;
            flex: auto;
            float: left;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            z-index: auto;
        }
        .box1:hover {
            transform: scale(1.05);
            z-index: 1;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            background-color: rgb(228, 234, 239);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px rgba(116, 118, 120, 0.811);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

something weird is happening. when i m using backdrop filter on box1, then z-index isn't working when hovered. But when i m removing backdrop-filter, z-index is working properly when hovered. following is the code and please help me to make it work when both combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, just try to add `position:relative`:

```css
.container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            padding: 4rem 15rem;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .box1 {
            height: 200px;
            width: 150px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(50, 153, 237, 0.584);
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
            margin: 40px -70px;
            padding: 50px;
            display: flex;
            flex: auto;
            float: left;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            position: relative;
            z-index: auto;
        }
        .box1:hover {
            transform: scale(1.05);
            z-index: 1;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            background-color: rgb(228, 234, 239);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px rgba(116, 118, 120, 0.811);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```